# Drag finger on X axis of mc, changes value - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have a rectangle mc. When the user swipes his finger slowly right on the mc, a value needs to increase, If moved left, it will decrease. 1 to 100 is the limit. How do I do that? i don't want a visible slider. It should not matter where the finger is on the mc, only which direction the finger is moving.

EDIT: I am currently looking into the touchEvent and am researching the web for solutions.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I am guessing it's something with myMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE ,myFunction); but how to do it on x axis.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to keep track of whether or not a swipe is happening and, if so, where it started.

```
var dragging:Boolean = false;
var startX:Number = 0.0;
```

Then you'll use simple event listeners to keep track of this bool.

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDown);
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseReleased); 
function mouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    dragging = true;
    startX = event.localX;
} 
function mouseReleased(event:MouseEvent):void 
{ 
    dragging = false;
}
```

Then you're `MOUSE_MOVE` touch event can handle all the logic:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMove); // Notice this event is on stage, not mc.
function mouseMove(event.MouseEvent):void
{
    value += event.localX - startX;
    if (value < 0) value = 0;
    if (value > 100) value = 100;
}
```

Happy Holidays!

Comment: Thank You for your help. var startX:Number = 0.0f;    throws a syntax error. expecting semicolon before f.   I also get an undefined property error with "value" which I guess I could define and use myValue instead? Happy Holidays to you too!

Comment: Yea. the `f` was a typo and you should replace `value` with whatever you're using to store the number that's changing.